# Visual Studio Emulator for Android is not updated

Tags: android, visual-studio, android-emulator, visual-studio-2015

I used Visual Studio 2015 with service pack 1. In device profile available only API 19.

[image]

I see a warning:

> Unable to establish a connect to the internet. Only device profile for acquired platforms are shown.

How do I fix this error?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Can you access to `http://www.msftncsi.com/ncsi.txt` from that machine? May be a `proxy/firewall` issue.

Comment: I disabled the firewall. But emulator is not updated.

Comment: In my file system32/hosts msftncsi.com was blocking.

Comment: Yeah - if you've installed stuff that blocks Microsoft collection of data from your computer you likely need to edit `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc` and remove blocked hosts. Thank you for this!