# Visual Studio Emulator for Android can't connect to internet

Tags: xamarin, android-emulator

I Have just installed VS emulator for Android but when I run it it says:"Unable to establish a connection to the internet. Only device profiles for acquired platforms are shown".

I have a virtual machine of ESX VMWare with Windows 10 pro and hyper-V installed

Any idea please?

Regads

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual Studio Android Emulator network not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36622890/visual-studio-android-emulator-network-not-working)

Comment: Check the [system requirements](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt228280.aspx), then work through troubleshooting guides [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/debug-on-emulator/visual-studio-android-emulator/#Troubleshooting) & [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt228282.aspx). A proxy/firewall issue was the problem on a similar [post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34420163/6146870). Check out [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve the chances of getting help on future questions